# Получение ботом Telegrama альбома фотографий на php

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Для работы с  Telegramm  я использую Laravel/Botman. Я могу получать от пользователя фотографии по одной. Если пользователь отправляет несколько фотографий, то у меня получается два события. Первое срабатывает, когда загрузилась первая фотография и так же соответственно по второму фото. Есть ли способ получить сразу два фото, если пользователь отправил их альбомом?
Я так понимаю этот метод отправляет альбом от бота пользователя https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmediagroup но, не наоборот.

Comment: "Вопрос состоит в том, что я могу получать от пользователя фотографии по одной." -- в этом вопрос не состоит никак.

Comment: Изменил формулировку